# Confirmation Box on closing browser in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, ecmascript-6

I have a use case where i want to render a confirmation box when user ties close a browser tab in my react application.

I have a queue which contains the requests to be made to the backend server. I want to render confirmation dialog with some custom message if queue is not empty and user closes browser tab.

Are there any recommended libraries or workflow hwich I should follow to achieve this??

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) function, to show a popup before closing the browser window.

Eg: Inside the `componentDidMount` of your component, write the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  if( //queue not empty ) {
    return;
  }
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

This is not in anyway related to React, but just a function provided by the window object. Also check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Hi Dane, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload. I can see here that the support for custom messages have been removed. I am looking for a component like NavigationPrompt in react-router which is available and I can use.

Comment: Yes, I see that too. But it seems you can invoke any function from within the function. So you may include, for eg: `yourModal.show()` inside this function. The downside is the window popup will still be visible.

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


/**
 * Confirm browser exit.
 *
 * @param defaultEnabled Start as enabled?
 * @param message Custom message (old browsers only).
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event
 */
export const useConfirmBrowserExit = (
  defaultEnabled = true,
  message = 'Confirm leave page'
) => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState<string>(message);
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState<boolean>(defaultEnabled);

  useEffect(() => {
    function listener(e: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
      if (enabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = msg;
        return msg;
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', listener);
    };
  }, [msg, enabled]);

  return {
    enable(): void {
      setEnabled(true);
    },
    disable(): void {
      setEnabled(false);
    },
    setMessage(newMessage: string): void {
      setMsg(newMessage);
    },
    getMessage(): string {
      return msg;
    },
    setEnabled(status: boolean): void {
      setEnabled(status);
    },
    getEnabled(): boolean {
      return enabled;
    },
  };
};
```

#### Note

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

> The support for custom messages have been removed.

Comment: Nice solution, but it does not work in Mozilla due to the fact that modern browsers not support this functionality anymore.